# How to alias pair member-data in C++?

Tags: c++, alias, key-value, std-pair

### How to alias pair member-data in C++ ?

I have a container of `std::pair<int,int>` to store *master-slave* pairs.

For better readability I want to use something like:

```
using Master = std::pair<int,int>::first;

std::pair<int,int> myPair;
auto myMaster = myPair.Master;
```

What would be the correct syntax here?

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Consider using `struct whatever { int master, slave; };` rather than `std::pair` if your thing is not just a pair of ints.

Comment: No, you cannot, because what you put in `pair` is internal to it, you have no control on how it store it. Consider writing your own struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be to use the tuple-like [`get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/get) access to `std::pair` with a self-defined constant:

```
const std::size_t Master = 0;

std::pair<int,int> myPair;
auto myMaster = std::get< Master >( myPair );
```

Somewhat cleaner and more readable than pointered access IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

You can name a pointer-to-member

```
constexpr auto Master = &std::pair<int,int>::first;

std::pair<int,int> myPair;
auto myMaster = myPair.*Master;
```

Comment: Here `myMaster` works with `myPair` only. Not any `std::pair<int,int>`.

Comment: @Supreeto `myMaster` is *copied* from `myPair.first`

Answer (score 0):

I am going with the following:

```cpp
int main() {
    cout<<"Hello World\n";
    
    constexpr auto Master = &std::pair<int,int>::first;

    std::pair<int,int> myPair;
    std::pair<int,int> myPair2;

    myPair.*Master = 321;
    myPair2.*Master = 10;
    cout<<myPair.*Master;
    cout<<myPair2.*Master;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks @[Caleth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2610810/caleth)

Comment: Is the clarity won by naming `Master` worth the clarity lost by the `.*Master` construct? I don't feel it is, especially as there is nothing keeping anybody from accessing `.*Master` as `.first`, adding inconsistency. Of course YMMV.

Comment: @DevSolar Personally, I favour `.first`. But in this code-base having `Master` is worth more than not having `.*`.

Comment: Hmmm.... you *could* define `Master = 0` and then go `std::get< Master >( myPair )`. (Just brainstorming here.)

Comment: @DevSolar, thanks. I like this :)